How to get logs for auto-sign-outs by Outlook on Android installed via InTune
How do I find a log or error from Android Outlook signing itself out automatically after a seemingly successful sign-in?
I've got InTune-installed Outlook and Teams working on iOS, connecting to Office365.  The same appears to be working on Android, getting as far as logging in to Outlook and downloading a small number of emails.  However, within seconds Outlook logs itself out.  Similarly, Teams logs itself out on Android promptly.  No error messages are shown, and I haven't found a way yet to see why.
The InTune App Protection shows Check-Ins for iOS , but not for Android , so it seems to be failing before it gets there.
Sign-In Logs in Entra shows a successful login to Outlook.  The device enrolls in InTune properly and shows as Compliant.
